# Does anyone know where I can find this HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like 3 SELECT boxes that allow people to select the month, day, and year. I'm sure there are HTML pre-sets like this, right?

```
January  5  2006
```

And the user can select the date, which is just option boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a [jQuery Date picker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)?

Note: I am searching for the old school date picker which you asked. Will be back soon.

Edit: [This page](http://javascript.internet.com/forms/true-date-selector.html) has a similar html code which you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the html 5 `<input type="date" />` then degrade gracefully for browsers that do not support it yet.

To degrade gracefully use the following code, [taken from diveintohtml5 here](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-date).

```
<form>
  <input type="date">
</form>
...
<script>
  var i = document.createElement("input");
  i.setAttribute("type", "date");
  if (i.type == "text") {
    // No native date picker support :(
    // Use Dojo/jQueryUI/YUI/Closure to create one,
    // then dynamically replace that <input> element.
  }
</script>
```